# How to check for compiler support of certain keywords/attributes?

Tags: c, cmake, compilation

I want to use CMake to check if my C compiler supports:

- `__hidden`, or an equivalent thereof such as `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`
- `restrict`, or an equivalent thereof

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: The approach which `autoconf` uses to test features like support for certain functions and features is to generate small test programs and run the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for various features by attempting to compile them with [`check_c_source_compiles`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckCSourceCompiles.html) and storing the result in a make variable. For instance you'd use these tests in CMakeLists.txt the check for the availability of `restrict` and `__hidden`:

```
check_c_source_compiles(
    "
        int f(void *restrict x);
        int main(void) {return 0;}
    "
    HAVE_RESTRICT
)

check_c_source_compiles(
    "
        typedef struct s *t;
        int f(t __restrict x);
        int main(void) {return 0;}
    "
    HAVE___RESTRICT
)

check_c_source_compiles(
    "
        __hidden int f() {return 1;}
        int main(void) {return 0;}
    "
    HAVE___HIDDEN
)

check_c_source_compiles(
    "
        #include <stdlib.h>
        static void f(void) __attribute__ ((visibility(\"hidden\")));
        int main(void) {return 0;}
    "
    HAVE___ATTRIBUTE__VISIBILITY_HIDDEN
)
```

There are some examples here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Utilities/cmliblzma/CMakeLists.txt

For the `restrict` keyword specifically, availability can be determined by the presence of `c_restrict` in the [`CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES.html) variable:

```
if (c_restrict IN_LIST CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES)
    [...]
endif()
```

Comment: Can you write down specifically how to I check that `c_restrict` is in the compiler's feature set?

Comment: Also, will these have 0/1 values, or be defined/undefined